# Access Denied while sending email from AWS SES in Lambda function

Tags: javascript, email, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am trying to send an email using Amazon SES in AWS Lambda function, For this i am facing the following error.

> AccessDenied: User `arn:aws:sts::XXXXX:assumed-role/lambda_basic_execution/awslambda_XXXX' is not authorized to perform`ses:SendEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:XXX:identity/example@example.com'

I have granted permission for

> "ses:SendEmail", "ses:SendRawEmail" for the IAM role.

Comment: Can you include the policy that you have applied to the *lambda_basic_execution* role?

Comment: Please find the below policies - {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "StmtXXXXXXXXX",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: For anyone still having trouble, you need to authorise the ec2/lambda role for SendEmail and SendRawEmail on *any* resource first (see Rakesh's comment/Nishith's answer), in addition to setting the SES identity policy to allow your role to send email.

Answer (score 70):

So, I was also having the same problem which Rakesh has explained but couldn't understand the steps he was saying to do so here is a detailed explanation with steps.

You need to do the following 
Security, Identity & Compliance -> IAM -> Roles -> select your lambda function -> then edit policy -> open it in JSON and add the below part

```
{
  "Effect":"Allow",
  "Action":[
    "ses:SendEmail",
    "ses:SendRawEmail"
  ],
  "Resource":"*"
}
```

or you can do as per requirement from these policy examples https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html#iam-and-ses-examples-email-sending-actions
also, you need to verify the email address first so don't forget that. Hope this helps everyone.

Comment: For a more restrictive policy, you can set the specific arn of the SES identity (AND arn of the email template if you are using `ses:SendTemplatedEmail`):

"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:01234:identity/example@gmail.com",
    "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:01234:template/example-template"
]

Comment: How did you learn that ses:SendRawEmail should be added also?

Comment: @SerhiiKushchenko I don't remember exactly, but it should only be required if you are sending raw emails or emails with attachments.

Answer (score 13):

If you are configuring policies for a SAM Lambda or using a YAML configuration file, you would use something like this:

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: 'your-email-lambda'

Resources:
  YourEmailFunction:
    Type: AWS:Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Policies:
        - Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'ses:SendEmail'
                - 'ses:SendRawEmail'
              Resource: '*'
```

Answer (score 11):

After a long debugging i got the issue, "lambda_basic_execution" role need to be granted with permission to access "ses:SendEmail", "ses:SendRawEmail".

Where i was trying to grant permission for the new IAM role i have created, but lambda function is mapped to "lambda_basic_execution" so there is a mismatch.

Reference - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html#iam-and-ses-examples-email-sending-actions

Comment: Could you paste the final policy that worked for you? I am still having this issue as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As what others said you should add this two permissions: ses:SendEmail,ses:SendRawEmail

I just want to add explaination for those who use Serverless framework

In serverless.yml:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: us-west-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
        - ses:SendEmail            # add this
        - ses:SendRawEmail         # add this
      Resource: '*'                # add this
```

Answer (score 2):

IAM Policy fixed the issue. Policy summary will show if there are any warnings i.e. resource does not exist etc.

JSON needs following

```
       {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**: You got permission error. your lambda iam identity needs to implement this missing iam policy - right action ( `ses:SendEmail` ) and right effect ( `Allow` ) to gain access permissions to this resource ( `verified domain - arn` ). on terraform you can add the following iam policy:

```
  statement {
    actions   = ["ses:SendEmail"]
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:XXX:identity/example@example.com"]
    sid = "emailFromAWSLambdaServerlessMachine"
  }
```

As a result - your policy will look like following:

```
{
  "Effect":"Allow",
  "Action":[
    "ses:SendEmail"
  ],
  "Resource":"arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:XXX:identity/example@example.com",
  "Sid": "emailFromAWSLambdaServerlessMachine"
}
```

**P.S** try avoid applying `*` as a resource or an action and limit access as much as possible for mitigate a security risks.

Comment: This is the best answer, BUT one must know that SES initially operates in a restricted "sandbox" mode, so it will produce badly worded errors for a policy that specifies exact ARN. In order for this policy to work, SES must be moved out of sandbox mode by filling a special form. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console

Answer (score 1):

In AWS console go to SES. You have to create SMTP credentials, SES sends you to  IAM.
Once you have the SMTP user there in the SMTP user you will find the credentials tab. Create the access key. Don't forget to save the secret access key.

Then you can check that the credential key work fine with this code:

```
$SesClient = new SesClient([
    'version' => '2010-12-01',
    'region'  => 'us-east-2',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'AKERTCVHAU4ODZ5VQZWP',
        'secret' => '88b7KEDS/XrmPjvy0YukQoPOAlW3eq+OnuDcyl0K',
    ],  
]);
```

AWS recommend to use the /.aws folder with a file named credentials (without extension) to put the credentials there:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKERTCVHAU4ODZ5VQZWP
aws_secret_access_key = 88b7KEDSXrmPjvy0YukQoPOAlW3eq+OnuDcyl0K
```

Then in IAM go to the SMTP user, permissions tab and edit the policy. Check you have this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "ses:SendEmail"
            ],
        "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Serverless Components yaml:

```
...
inputs:
  name: ${name}-${stage}
  region: ...
  service: lambda.amazonaws.com
  policy:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - ses:SendEmail
        - ses:SendRawEmail
      Resource: '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found @modsquadron's template.yaml answer didn't work, but this variation does - if you are configuring policies for a SAM Lambda, try:

`template.yaml`

```
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Policies:
        - Statement:
            - Sid: SESSendEmailToAllPolicy
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'ses:SendEmail'
                - 'ses:SendRawEmail'
                - 'ses:SendTemplatedEmail'
              Resource: '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to IAM > Users > and the user you have > Permissions and then under the Permissions boundary, I had the permissions boundary S3FullAccess then I changed it to SESFullAcess. It solved the problem for me